# html dom parser php array

Tags: php, html-parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

The code above works but return only first element of the array, probably because I set 0 in $item. If I delete 0 I get "Array" message. How to get the complete loop and put it in my table output? Thanks.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = "http://www.theurlscraped.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);

foreach($html->find('div[class=class0]') as $post) {

$item['url'] = $post->find('a.class1', 0)->href;
$item['image'] = $post->find('img.class2', 0)->src;
$item['descrizione'] = $post->find('span.class3', 0)->plaintext;
$item['price'] = $post->find('span.class4', 0);
}?>
```

EDIT: Structure of the page to be scraped:

```
<div class="class0">
    <a class="class1" href="/another/page">
        <span class="class3">
            <span class="class6">
                Hello world!
            </span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore....
        </span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span class="class4">tag</span>
                <span class="class5">tagtag</span>
            </span>
            <img class="class2" src="http://www.urlsourceimage.com/img.jpg">
        </span>
    </a>
    <a class="class1" href="/another/page">
        <span class="class3">
            <span class="class6">
                Hello world, this is me! 
            </span>
        Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span class="class4">tag1</span>
                <span class="class5">tagtag1</span>
            </span>
            <img class="class2" src="http://www.urlsourceimage.com/img1.jpg">
        </span>
    </a>

    ...

    <a class="class1" href="/another/page">
        <span class="class3">
            <span class="class6">
                Life should be fun for everyone!
            </span>
        Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
        <span>
            <span>
                <span class="class4">tag2</span>
                <span class="class5">tagtag2</span>
            </span>
            <img class="class2" src="http://www.urlsourceimage.com/img2.jpg">
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Desire output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><a href="<?php echo $item['url'];?>"><img src="<?php echo $item['image'];?>" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $item['url'];?>">Price: <?php echo $item['price'];?></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['descrizione'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $item['url'];?>">dettagli offerta &raquo;</a></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['price'];?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:
I try also this solution but returns and infinite loop:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.theurlscraped.com');


foreach($html->find('div[class=class0]') as $table) {
$urls = $table->find('a.class1');
$images = $table->find('img.class2');
$descrizioni = $table->find('span.class3');

    foreach($urls as $url)
    foreach($images as $image)
    foreach($descrizioni as $descrizione)
    {
        echo "URL = " . $url->href ."<br />";
        echo "Img = " . $image->src ."<br />";
        echo "Descrizione = " . $descrizione ."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to scrape a site and show some stuff in there which are displayed within class0 in a table, what you need is:

You need to remove 0's wherever you request a find within the main foreach loop, and wrap another loop around those find statements in this fashion:

`foreach($post->find('a.class1') as $element)`

And you need to echo the $element under these internal loops, wrapping them in their convenient columns and rows.

Let me know if you do not understand, I will write the whole thing to you in the evening when I m less busy. Thanks

Comment: Thanks BeQI for the quick reply. I'll try but I'm pretty sure I'll need again your help :)

Comment: One more quick thing to try is, echo the scraped code as it is and handle its representation with css, it is much easier than getting ->href, ->src, ->plaintext one by one and rewriting the whole thing

Comment: for your last suggestion I think it is not possibile because in scraped code teere are relative links (e.g. /category/product/item1) don't work in my website.

Comment: concerning your answer: I tried this:
foreach($html->find('div[class=class0]') as $post) {
foreach($post->find('a.class1') as $link) {
echo "<a href=\".$link->href.\">TEST</a><br />";
} }

and it works but I don't know how to add all the other element... in fact if I add another foreach the two element remain separeted and I'm not able to combine them... Could you please help me?

Comment: Hi Im back, sorry didnt go online last night, so what other elements do you need printed? maybe try and explain all the requirements, the url you are trying to scrape and the exact spot than I can be of help?

Comment: One thing is, do you know which classes will be link and which will be text? we could try and write a more clever array parsing algorithm depending on information you give me :)